# Join error in using CTE in Hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

i have two queries which are doing almost the similar work.
One does it without CTEs and one with CTEs. I am unable to figure out why the second query is giving absolutely no results while the first one is.

I have spent the last two hours trying to figure this out by trying out various joins and the same joins working in query 1 are not working in query 2. I hope someone can guide me with this.

First query (Returns results):

```
WITH MessageCTE AS 
    (
    SELECT dt
    , id
    , ts
    , family
    , message_type
    , to_user
    , message_id
    , class
    FROM dhruv.MessageLatencyInformation_20171210_20171125_to_20171130_02 as latencydata
    INNER JOIN dhruv.UsersOn503AndAbove_20171201_200k as required_users
    ON latencydata.to_user = required_users.user_id
    )
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT to_user) AS Users
, AVG(latency) AS AvgLatency
, AVG(CASE WHEN latency > 0 THEN latency ELSE NULL END) AS AvgLatency_Positive
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.5) AS 50Percentile
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.75) AS 75Percentile
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.8) AS 80Percentile
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.9) AS 90Percentile
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.95) AS 95Percentile
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.99) AS 99Percentile
FROM
    (
    SELECT a.dt, a.to_user, (latency_dl.ts - latency_pb.ts) as latency
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT dt
        , id, ts
        , family
        , message_type
        , to_user
        , message_id
        , class
        FROM MessageCTE
        WHERE class = 'pb'
        ) as latency_pb
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT dt
        , id
        , ts
        , family
        , message_type
        , to_user
        , message_id
        , class
        FROM MessageCTE
        WHERE class = 'rdl'
        AND family = 'stm'
        ) as latency_rdl
    ON latency_pb.dt = latency_rdl.dt and latency_pb.to_user = latency_rdl.to_user and latency_pb.id = latency_rdl.id
    INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT dt
        , id
        , ts
        , family
        , message_type
        , to_user
        , message_id
        , class
        FROM MessageCTE
        WHERE class = 'dl'
        ) as latency_dl
    ON latency_rdl.dt = latency_dl.dt and latency_rdl.to_user = latency_dl.to_user and latency_rdl.id = latency_dl.id) AS UserLatency;
```

First Query Output:
[image: First Query Output]

Now Second Query, is a slight modification and all the same conditions, but for some reason it is returning no matches. Hopefully someone can guide me out, i just spent around 2 hours trying some joins out and i am unable to figure out why they are not happening.

Second Query:

```
WITH MessageCTE_pb AS 
    (
    SELECT dt, id, ts, to_user
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT dt, id, min(ts) as ts, to_user
        FROM dhruv.MessageLatencyInformation_20171210_20171125_to_20171130_02
        WHERE class = 'pb'
        GROUP BY dt, to_user, id
        ) as latencydata
    INNER JOIN dhruv.UsersOn503AndAbove_20171201_200k as required_users
    ON latencydata.to_user = required_users.user_id
    )
, MessageCTE_dl AS 
    (
    SELECT dt, id, ts, to_use
    FROM
        (
        SELECT dt, id, max(ts) as ts, to_user 
        FROM dhruv.MessageLatencyInformation_20171210_20171125_to_20171130_02 
        WHERE class = 'dl' 
        GROUP BY dt, to_user, id
        ) as latencydata
    INNER JOIN dhruv.UsersOn503AndAbove_20171201_200k as required_users
    ON latencydata.to_user = required_users.user_id
    )
, MessageCTE_rdl AS 
    (
    SELECT dt, id, to_user
    FROM
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT dt, id, to_user 
        FROM dhruv.MessageLatencyInformation_20171210_20171125_to_20171130_02
        WHERE class = 'rdl' 
        AND family = 'stm'
        ) as latencydata 
    INNER JOIN dhruv.UsersOn503AndAbove_20171201_200k as required_users
    ON latencydata.to_user = required_users.user_id
    )
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT to_user) AS Users 
, AVG(latency) AS AvgLatency 
, AVG(CASE WHEN latency > 0 THEN latency ELSE NULL END) AS AvgLatency_Positive 
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.5) AS 50Percentile 
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.75) AS 75Percentile 
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.8) AS 80Percentile 
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.9) AS 90Percentile 
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.95) AS 95Percentile 
, PERCENTILE(latency, 0.99) AS 99Percentile
FROM
    (
    SELECT a.dt, a.to_user, (latency_dl.ts - latency_pb.ts) as latency
    FROM MessageCTE_pb as latency_pb
    INNER JOIN MessageCTE_rdl as latency_rdl
    ON latency_pb.dt = latency_rdl.dt and latency_pb.to_user = latency_rdl.to_user and latency_pb.id = latency_rdl.id
    INNER JOIN MessageCTE_dl as latency_dl
    ON latency_rdl.dt = latency_dl.dt and latency_rdl.to_user = latency_dl.to_user and latency_rdl.id = latency_dl.id) AS UserLatency;
```

Thanks!

Second Query Result:
[image: Second Query Result]

Comment: I'm guessing that you haven't read this?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Try breaking your query down piece by piece until you find out at which step it diverges.  There is far to much extraneous code here for people to filter through to play spot the difference.  Also, try using indentation make it clear where sub queries begin and end.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Mat, i am aware of the breaking it down bit by bit and i did try it but I am unable to spot the difference. At this point i did decide to share it with the community as i continue my search.
I will edit the subqueries and indent them as well.

Comment: You consider that to be a `slight` modification?

Comment: Are you using the aliases `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `p`, `q`, `r`, `s`, `t`, and `u` just to make this harder?

Comment: I am sorry, i chose to use distinct alphabets as the aliases so that it could be distinguishable from others as i could not give them other meaningful names without adding to the length and the confusion.

Comment: Yet you managed to choose meaningful names when using CTEs?

Comment: I will change the aliases to make it more readable. I apologise for that.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious.  My best advice would be to re-write the queries to not have any of the latency calculations and just end with the `COUNT(DISTINCT to_user)`.  Run it with just the `_pb` sub-query / CTE, then add the join back in for `_rdl`, then add back in the join for `_dl`.  At each step check that both queries are giving you the same number of users.

Comment: Thanks Mat, will go through that again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161658/discussion-between-dk5-and-matbailie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another comment in an answer block so I can post a bunch of SQL...

What is the result of this?

```
WITH
    UserLatency AS 
(
    SELECT
        latencydata.dt,
        latencydata.to_user,
        latencydata.id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN latencydata.class = 'dl' THEN latencydata.ts END)
        -
        MIN(CASE WHEN latencydata.class = 'pb' THEN latencydata.ts END)
            AS latency
    FROM
        dhruv.MessageLatencyInformation_20171210_20171125_to_20171130_02   AS latencydata
    INNER JOIN
        dhruv.UsersOn503AndAbove_20171201_200k                             AS required_users
            ON latencydata.to_user = required_users.user_id
    GROUP BY
        latencydata.dt,
        latencydata.to_user,
        latencydata.id
    HAVING
        0 < SUM(CASE WHEN latencydata.class  = 'rdl'
                      AND latencydata.family = 'stm' THEN 1 END)
)
SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT to_user)                       AS Users
    , AVG(latency)                                  AS AvgLatency 
    , AVG(CASE WHEN latency > 0 THEN latency END)   AS AvgLatency_Positive 
    , PERCENTILE(latency, 0.50)                     AS 50Percentile 
    , PERCENTILE(latency, 0.75)                     AS 75Percentile 
    , PERCENTILE(latency, 0.80)                     AS 80Percentile 
    , PERCENTILE(latency, 0.90)                     AS 90Percentile 
    , PERCENTILE(latency, 0.95)                     AS 95Percentile 
    , PERCENTILE(latency, 0.99)                     AS 99Percentile
FROM
    UserLatency
;
```

Comment: Mat, this is beautiful And simple. Really liked it! :) 
Thank you very much! 
My query worked on rewriting as well, but this is very good, super optimized and i was just missing out on looking at it like this. Much appreciated sire! :)

Comment: @DK5 - You're welcome.  It's often the case that joining similar/related rows from the same table can be done via aggregation instead.  With appropriate indexes that gives you faster execution as well as shorter code.

Comment: Thank you very much Mat, i can see the simplicity you added to it, its amazing. Very clearly visible how you got that 51.1k reputation! Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Flattery will get you everywhere.

Comment: Just meant to appreciate your help. Thank you once again!